# Why is my text aligned to the left?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android developing, and I just couldn't fix this problem. When I build this app, my initial text is centered, but when I click the button or long click it, the response text is left aligned. And also, double tap, scrolling and flinging gestures don't work at all. What can be the reason?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.revolise.gesturehandling;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
    {

        private Button button1;
        private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetect;
        private TextView txt1;


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            this.gestureDetect = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
            gestureDetect.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

            button1.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            txt1.setText("clicked to the button whooaoaaa");
                        }
                    }
            );

            button1.setOnLongClickListener(
                    new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                            txt1.setText("long clicked to the button woww");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
            );


        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            txt1.setText("Hey, you double tapped");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            txt1.setText("Aaaand now you're swiping.");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            txt1.setText("Scrolling weee");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            txt1.setText("Long pressed");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            txt1.setText("Whoaa flinginggg");
            return true;
        }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.revolise.gesturehandling.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:text="@string/initial_text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: alright, I added it.

Comment: what do you mean with "scrolling and flinging gestures don't work at all". What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For first problem (wrong text aligned)**

You should set your TextView width as match_parent and gravity to center_horizontal. So your code should be something like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:text="@string/initial_text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Done. Can you check the second one too?

Comment: @AhmetEmreBoyacı yes , explain better please what do you want to do (you want to have a scroll screen?) and what is wrong (what exception / issue happen)

Comment: ok, the thing is, I'm just trying to implement the scroll,fling and double tap kind of gestures (the methods in GestureDetector.OnGestureListener and GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener to be specific) and the TextView should say something like "Scrolling" when it catches a scrolling event, and "Flinging" when it catches a flinging event etc.